# ¿Math.sqrt se considera una operación elemental en términos de eficiencia?

Tags: java

Necesitaría saber si Math.sqrt (Java) es una operación elemental (tiempo de ejecución constante, O(1)) en un algoritmo para poder definir el coste computacional de un método. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Un artículo de stack overflow (en inglés) dice que son implementaciones nativas y no hay mejora en desempeño al implementar java puro para equiparar la función.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263948/fast-sqrt-in-java-at-the-expense-of-accuracy

Comment: En el artículo hay un vínculo a la implementación, para analizar su coste computacional o la velocidad del algoritmo. https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java